# R will produce a string array on Mac but a factor on Windows

Tags: r, rstudio

I am accessing a data frame generated from a CSV file I read in with read.csv().

The end goal is this: Look at rows where `aColumn` is the value of  `value[i]`, and get the value of `anotherColumn` from these rows (stored in `tmpC`). Later this will be reduced to a single string of AVALUE or DIFFERENTVALUE.
As you can see, the `tmpC` variable gets me an array (?) of strings I could then reduce down to a single string with `head()`. Cool. On windows, not so much. I get a factor.

What is happening?

[image]

Comment: One possibility: Starting with R 4.0.0, the default for many functions (including `read.csv()`) is now `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.  Either ensure you have the same versions of R on both OSes or manually set the `stringsAsFactors` argument in your call to `read.csv()`

Comment: That was it, I didn't realize I had a 3.xx version of R installed! Thanks!